# How to increase the vertical length of one element in a grid?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an `ion-grid` and I want the right element to increase its vertical length so it would consume the empty space and has the exact the same vertical length like the two left elements. The only thing I achieved was that the left element increased in horizontal length but this is not what I want to achieve here.

[image: Grid]

```
 <ion-list>        
    <ion-card>
        <ion-row>
        <div class="card-title">  El 1</div> 
        </ion-row>    
    </ion-card>

    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-card>  
            </ion-card>   
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-card>    
            </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row >
          <ion-col>
              <ion-card>
              </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
         </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  <ion-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

For more complex grid layouts than the ones provided by default in ion-grid, you can use CSS-grid-layout -- see docs:  [Basic Concepts of Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

For your specific example you would have to set the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

        <ion-card  class="box1">
            <div>  box1</div> 
        </ion-card>

      <ion-card  class="box2">
            <div >  box2</div> 
        </ion-card>

        <ion-card  class="box3">
            <div >  box3</div> 
        </ion-card>

      <ion-card  class="box4">
            <div >  box4</div> 
        </ion-card>

      <ion-card  class="box5">
            <div >  box5</div> 
        </ion-card>

  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper { 
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; 
} 

.box2 { 
  grid-column-start: 2; 
  grid-row-start: 1; 
  grid-row-end: 3; 
}
```

Result:

[Grid layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REKWd.png)

And of course, now you can easily rearrange or modify all of them by referring to each box's class

And it is a very widely supported featured nowadays (>95%)! https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

---

However, if you are forced to use ion-grid, one option would be to set two different columns and then occupy the left one with 2 rows, and the right one with 1 row and height set to 100%.

This results in a much more complex and less flexible code, hence I would recommend CSS-layout-grid instead.

To achieve the same result as the image above you would use:

```
<ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-row>
                <ion-card>  
                    <div>  box1</div> 
                </ion-card>   
              </ion-row>
              <ion-row>
                <ion-card>    
                    <div>  box2</div> 
                </ion-card>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-col>

            <ion-col>
                <ion-row style="height: 100%;">
                    <ion-card>
                        <div>  box3</div> 
                    </ion-card>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row >
            <ion-col>
                  <ion-card>
                      <div>  box4</div> 
                  </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                  <ion-card>
                      <div>  box5</div> 
                  </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```